# Typescript: How to set values of in an array of objects from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Let's say I have two arrays...

```
array1 = [{'age':'', 'name':'John'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Mark'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Curtis'}]


array2 = ['23','25','29']
```

I know I can use a nested for loop to set the 'age' object to the values in array2. But is there another way with one of the javascript methods like find or map? So the desired outcome would be...

```
array3 = [{'age':'23', 'name':'John'}, {'age':'25', 'name':'Mark'}, {'age':'29', 'name':'Curtis'}]
```

Also what is array2 was...

```
array2 = [{'value':'23'},{'value':'25'},{'value':'29'}]
```

Could I do the same thing even if the objects have different names? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` and take the `age` from the 1st array using the index (`i`), and combine using object destructuring:

```js
const array1 = [{'age':'', 'name':'John'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Mark'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Curtis'}]
const array2 = ['23','25','29']

const result = array1.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, age: array2[i] }))

console.log(result)
```

Handle the 2nd version of `array2` is similar, use the index, and take the value:

```js
const array1 = [{'age':'', 'name':'John'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Mark'}, {'age':'', 'name':'Curtis'}]
array2 = [{'value':'23'},{'value':'25'},{'value':'29'}]

const result = array1.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, age: array2[i].value }))

console.log(result)
```